# Установить разные initial-scale на айпаде для landscape и portrait

Tags: ipad, javascript

Нужно на айпаде для landscape и portrait установить разные значения для метатега `viewport`.  
Пробую два разных варианта скрипта, ни один не работает корректно
**1 вариант**

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {   
      function onOrientationChange()
      {
    var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
    switch(window.orientation) 
    {  
      case -90:
      case 90:
        viewportmeta.content = 'initial-scale=0.6';
        break; 
      default:
        viewportmeta.content = 'initial-scale=0.8';
        break; 
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', onOrientationChange);
  onOrientationChange();
}
```

**2 вариант**

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {             
          window.onorientationchange = detectIPadOrientation;
          function detectIPadOrientation () {
            var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');

            if ( orientation == 0 ) {
             viewportmeta.content = 'initial-scale=0.6';
            }
            else if ( orientation == 90 ) {
             viewportmeta.content = 'initial-scale=0.8';
            }
            else if ( orientation == -90 ) {
             viewportmeta.content = 'initial-scale=0.8';
            }
            else if ( orientation == 180 ) {
             viewportmeta.content = 'initial-scale=0.6';
            }
          }
}
```

Как можно заставить скрипт работать?

**up**